# Why `Delete` does not work?

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm trying random things in Mathematica just for learning and I can't solve this problem. I want to use the `Delete` function to delete some elements in a list but it's not working.
My program consists of this:

I get the $n$ Weather stations closest to Chicago:

```
stations = WeatherData[{"Chicago", 20}]
```

> {"C3175", "KCGX", "C8163", "D3691", "KMDW", "D1866", "AN168", "AS937", "AN169", "C2741", "C5827", "C9647", "D2206", "AP878", "C3332", "C5247", "C8740", "C6091", "AT367", "AR820"}

Then, I make a list with the temperature at each station and save it in a list with the date at which the temperature was taken:

```
temperatures = {DateObject[WeatherData[stations[[#]], "Temperature","DateValue"][[1, 1]]],WeatherData[stations[[#]], "Temperature"]} & /@ Range[Length[stations]]
```

> {{DateObject[{2014, 11, 24}],
> Quantity[-1., "DegreesCelsius"]}, {DateObject[{2008, 6, 18}],
> Quantity[14., "DegreesCelsius"]}, {DateObject[{2008, 3, 28}],
> Quantity[2.8, "DegreesCelsius"]}, {DateObject[{2013, 3, 8}],
> Quantity[0.6, "DegreesCelsius"]}, {DateObject[{2014, 11, 24}],
> Quantity[-1., "DegreesCelsius"]}, {DateObject[{2014, 11, 24}],
> Quantity[-2.1, "DegreesCelsius"]}, {DateObject[{2011, 12, 28}],
> Missing["NotAvailable"]}, {DateObject[{2014, 11, 24}],
> Quantity[-1., "DegreesCelsius"]}, {DateObject[{2012, 12, 18}],
> Missing["NotAvailable"]}, {DateObject[{2012, 1, 9}],
> Missing["NotAvailable"]}, {DateObject[{2011, 11, 8}],
> Quantity[-17.7, "DegreesCelsius"]}, {DateObject[{2010, 10, 30}],
> Quantity[14.4, "DegreesCelsius"]}, {DateObject[{2012, 8, 4}],
> Quantity[27.2, "DegreesCelsius"]}, {DateObject[{2014, 11, 24}],
> Quantity[-2.1, "DegreesCelsius"]}, {DateObject[{2011, 1, 28}],
> Missing["NotAvailable"]}, {DateObject[{2008, 5, 24}],
> Quantity[8.3, "DegreesCelsius"]}, {DateObject[{2008, 3, 10}],
> Quantity[-1., "DegreesCelsius"]}, {DateObject[{2011, 5, 20}],
> Quantity[21.7, "DegreesCelsius"]}, {DateObject[{2010, 11, 25}],
> Quantity[4.4, "DegreesCelsius"]}, {DateObject[{2014, 11, 24}],
> Quantity[-2.7, "DegreesCelsius"]}}

Now I try to delete every temperature that is not from today:

```
If[temperatures[[#, 1]] == Today, Print["Correct"],Delete[temperatures, #]] & /@ Range[Length[temperatures]]
```

But this is not working. When I check the length of the *temperatures* list, it's still 20. Indeed, I've tried:

```
temperatures[[#, 1]] == Today & /@ Range[Length[temperatures]]
```

> {True, False, False, False, True, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, True}

So the condition is fine.
Even trying this:

```
Delete[temperatures, 1]
```

The length of *temperatures* is still 20.
Why is this not working with the function `Delete`?

Comment: I recommend looking into the `Select` and `Cases` functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Delete` does not modify the object itself the element being deleted from.

```
x = {a, b, c, d};
Delete[x, 3]
```

`x` is still not changed now after the call to `Delete`. What you get back is the result of the deletion. To actually change `x` you need to assign this result back to the original object to change it:

```
x = Delete[x, 3]
```

Only now will `x` become

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Mathematica is not like Fortran, it is not a call by reference.

Comment: Thank you. Now I can see that was an stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = {a, b, c, d};
```

**1.**

Using [ApplyTo](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ApplyTo.html) (new in 12.2)

```
x //= Delete[3];

x
```

{a, b, d}

**2.**

Using [Nothing](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html) (new in 10.2)

```
x = {a, b, c, d};

x[[3]] = Nothing;

x
```

{a, b, d}

**3.**

Passing `x` by reference

```
SetAttributes[del, HoldAll]

del[x_, p_] := x = Delete[x, p]

x = {a, b, c, d};

del[x, 3];

x
```

{a, b, d}